# Using SQL Fiddle to share SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfiddle

I'd like to share my SQL Server code via SQL Fiddle. But I can't seem to get my schema created. I can get MySQL tables created no problem, but something won't cooperate when I switch to the SQL Server setting. I've looked across the internet for almost an hour now. can someone steer me straight?

Here's a table I'm trying to make for example:

```
create table employee
(
    empnum char(3) primary key,
    empname varchar(15),
    empphone char(4)
)
GO

insert into employee values('123', 'andrew', '1234')
insert into employee values('124', 'andy', '1221')
insert into employee values('125', 'andre', '1344')
GO
```

I keep getting:

> Create script error

Thank you.

Comment: What error did you receive? SQL Fiddle has been problematic lately. Try using [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) instead.

Comment: it is not working. See the developer's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321437/is-it-ok-to-promote-a-non-working-sql-fiddle)

Comment: "Create script error"

Comment: @FelixPamittan it will not allow users to create tables.

Comment: Use temporary tables instead. Just prefix your table names with `#`.

Comment: I have a dropbox, I mean, I could upload the DLL to a text file and share it via a link..

Comment: Or you could just put the DDL in the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's like 3 pages long... will stack allow that?

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old post, but had the same issue with the example code above in both MySQL and SQL Server.  However, I was able to get the following to run successfully:

```
create table employee
(
    empnum char(3) primary key,
    empname varchar(15),
    empphone char(4)
);

insert into employee values('123', 'andrew', '1234');
insert into employee values('124', 'andy', '1221');
insert into employee values('125', 'andre', '1344');
```

Hope this saves someone else a little time. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5649a

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers that SQL Fiddle is currently having issues with MS SQL Server code. I'm think I'm going to share it via dropbox link instead. Making temporary table son stack exchange sort of works, but I'm gonna have to ctrl + h every single instance of a table name...

crappy. I wish I hadn't spent an hour struggling on this. Thank you for all your help.